# Why View source of the page is different than Inspecting the element of the page

Tags: html, dom

Okay I'm using Producteev.com frequently on my projects, the other day I noticed that on my workspace page, that the source of the page (Ctrl+U) is quite short and most of the page's items are not in the view source code.

but of course if you inspect the elements of the page you see the actual codes.

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask such question but I'd like to know why is this happening and using what technology maybe? and also why they do use such techniques?

Comment: One is the actual source, the other is the source *after* it has been manipulated by JavaScript.

Comment: What you are saying is that they manipulated their source code with javascript? why they do that? and how's that possible?

Comment: There are hundreds of reasons why they might. It is possible because that is 99% of the point of having JavaScript support in web browsers in the first place. It was what the language was invented for!

Comment: @NicolasHenrard: LMGTFY comments are not considered constructive.

Comment: When the user is not able to type the right query in a search engine, I think it's more constructive to give him a link than to copy/paste a complete tutorial in SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing the source shows the source code.

Inspecting the DOM shows you a serialisation of the current state of the DOM after the HTML has been parsed, error corrected, normalised and (possibly) manipulated with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the source code is just like only 20 line of code which is quite weird for a lot of page elements

Comment: Then they did a lot of manipulation with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements that have been added dynamically after the page is generated will not be included in the page source.

Comment: What you mean added dynamically? like elements created by a JavaScript file ?

Comment: Excatly, JavaScript can be used to make the page more dynamic and enjoyable to use.

Comment: Also don't know why people keep down voting my question? because I'm not a professional as they are?

Comment: I voted it back up, seems like a perfectly valid question and one that confused me at first also.